# ¿Como insertar una palabra dividida por letras en un arreglo de dos dimensiones en java?

Tags: java, array, string

Mi programa necesita que inserte las letras de una palabra en un arreglo de dos dimensiones. Antes de eso, mi programa divide la palabra en letras y las coloca en un arreglo de tipo `char` . ¿Como inserto cada una de esas letras a mi arreglo de dos dimensiones?.

Comment: Hola, debes mejorar tu pregunta para que tenga la calidad mínima que requiere el sitio. Revisar [ask] para saber como formular una buena pregunta, agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.